# TypeError: Must be str not int

Tags: python, string, floating-point, int

I am using this code to concatenate strings with a float value :

```
fr = channel.freqhz / 1000000
print ("fr type is", type(fr))
rx_channel = "<RxChannel>\n\
  <IsDefault>1</IsDefault>\n\
  <UsedForRX2>" + channel.usedforrx2 + "</UsedForRX2>\n\
  <ChIndex>" + str(i) + "</ChIndex>\n\
  <LC>" + str(channel.index) + "</LC>\n\
  <SB>" + channel.subband + "</SB>\n\
  <DTC>100</DTC>\n\
  <Frequency>" + str(fr) + "</Frequency>\n\
  <MinDR>0</MinDR>\n\
  <MaxDR>5</MaxDR>\n\
</RxChannel>\n"
```

But I get this error message :

```
> fr type is <class 'float'>                                         
> Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
> File "createRFRegion.py", line 260, in <module>                       
> write_rf_region(rf_region_file, rf_region_filename)                   
> File "createRFRegion.py", line 233, in write_rf_region                
> rf_region_file.write(create_rx_channel(channel, i))                   
> File "createRFRegion.py", line 164, in create_rx_channel              
> <Frequency>" + str(fr) + "</Frequency>\n\                             
> TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I don't understand this error because I am using the str() function to convert the float to str.

Comment: thats wierd, just tried your code and it is correct. What is the exact line that you're having trouble with

Comment: This works for me, so it seems there's something else going on. Could you post more of your code?

Comment: The error must come from somewhere else in your code `line = "<Frequency>" + str(6.7) + "</Frequency>\n"` does not give me any error.

Comment: What are lines 163, 164 and 165 in the `createRFRegion.py` file? Sounds like a typo in there somewhere

Comment: https://repl.it/IZ9Z/0 - it works for me as well.

Comment: Curious, your error message shows `<Frequency>" + str(fr) + "</Frequency>\n` rather than `line = "<Frequency>" + str(fr) + "</Frequency>\n"`. Are you sure the code you're showing us is the code you're running?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy the whole code because I thought it was not relevant but now it seems it's coming from the missing code. I edit my post with the whole code...

Comment: Why are you getting the `>` prefix, are you running it on an IDE?  If so, try reloading the code, I ran your code (with dummy values) and the syntax looks fine.

Comment: No I'm running it in the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Just use `str()` in all fields.

Python doesn't deal well with multi-line operations and errors, and will point at the last line of the multi-line operation (I'm assuming it is joining together all the strings in the last line, and thus pointing at `str(fr)`).

The field `fr` isn't even an `int`, it's a `float`, so the error is coming from one of the other fields. My guess is `channel.subband`, a sub-band of a channel will be an integer.

```
rx_channel = "<RxChannel>\n<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>\n<UsedForRX2>" + 
    str(channel.usedforrx2) + "</UsedForRX2>\n<ChIndex>" + 
    str(i) + "</ChIndex>\n<LC>" + 
    str(channel.index) + "</LC>\n<SB>" + 
    str(channel.subband) + "</SB>\n<DTC>100</DTC>\n<Frequency>" + 
    str(fr) + "</Frequency>\n<MinDR>0</MinDR>\n<MaxDR>5</MaxDR>\n/RxChannel>\n"
```

Comment: You are right I have been misguided with the fact that Python doesn't deal well with multi-line operations and errors. I thought the error was coming from fr when it was coming from usedforrx2 which was not a str.

Answer (score 2):

What are values of `channel.usedforrx2` and `channel.subband`? I suspect one of them is int rather than string. Also, to make your code more readable, consider replacing that statement with:

```
rx_channel = """<RxChannel>
  <IsDefault>1</IsDefault>
  <UsedForRX2>{}</UsedForRX2>
  <ChIndex>{}</ChIndex>
  <LC>{}</LC>
  <SB>{}</SB>
  <DTC>100</DTC>
  <Frequency>{}</Frequency>
  <MinDR>0</MinDR>
  <MaxDR>5</MaxDR>
</RxChannel>
""".format(channel.usedforrx2, i, channel.index, channel.subband, fr)
```